Enabling Lambda Insights on Containerized Function
I'm attempting to add container insights to containerized Lambda function. I have added arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/CloudWatchLambdaInsightsExecutionRolePolicy to my function.
I added the following command to the DockerFile for the Lambda:
RUN curl -O https://lambda-insights-extension.s3-ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/amazon_linux/lambda-insights-extension.rpm && \
    rpm -U lambda-insights-extension.rpm && \
    rm -f lambda-insights-extension.rpm

Both were successfully added, but in the console it shows that no functions have insights enabled. 
I made sure to run the function as well.
I followed this documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Lambda-Insights-Getting-Started-docker.html
I tried adding Lambda insights through the console as well following this documentation https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Lambda-Insights-Getting-Started-console.html but the option does not appear in the additional monitoring settings

What am I missing for Lambda Insights to create data in the Cloudwatch?

I was just testing this myself and faced the same issue like you did. If you have deployed insights via a docker container, you wont see it in lambda insights pane in cloudwatch and neither will you be able to "enable" it from the lambda.
First of all, the lambda needs to have run if you want to generate lamda insights.
Go to: CloudWatch > On the left pane select log groups > Select "/aws/lambda-insights"
You can also see these insights in your metrics which is a much cleaner look compared to logs.
Hope that helps
